# Is my solution correct for the derivative of $\frac{\sin 3x}{\sqrt{3}}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Is my solution for the derivative of $\frac{\sin 3x}{\sqrt{3}}$ correct?

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin 3x}{\sqrt{3}} \\
& = \frac{0 \cdot \sin3x - \sqrt{3} \cdot 3\cos 3x}{(\sqrt{3})^2} \\
& = \frac{3 \cos 3x}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

I tried to verify through W|A but it says the answer is: $\sqrt{3} \cdot \cos 3x$. How can that be? Due to quotient rule, shouldn't there still be a $\sqrt{3}$ ?

EDIT:

Is it because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ simplifies to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and the $3$'s cancel out?

Comment: In case you misquoted W|A, recall $3/\sqrt 3 = \sqrt 3$.

Comment: To begin with, you got the wrong sign in the quotient rule. Now it is absolutely unneceesary to use the quotient rule here. Just take the factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ out from the beginning. Differentiation is linear, never forget that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin 3x}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac d{dx}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3} \cdot \sin 3x \right) = \frac1{\sqrt 3}\cdot 3 \cos 3x = \frac{3}{\sqrt 3} \cos 3x = \sqrt 3 \cos 3x \tag{1}$$

(And we can use the chain rule, only).

- Note that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ is a *constant*, so there's *really no need to use the quotient rule*. If you do use it, then the factors in your numerator should be reversed: $$d/dx\left(\dfrac{\sin 3x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) =\;\dfrac{(\sqrt 3)\cdot 3\cos 3x - 0\cdot \sin 3x}{(\sqrt 3)^2}.\;$$
- But aside from that, as you can see from $(1)$, *the answer you
  arrive at equals the simplified answer given by W|A.*

$(1)$ Note: $\; \dfrac 3{\sqrt 3} = \dfrac {\sqrt 3\cdot 3}{(\sqrt 3)^2} = \dfrac {3\cdot \sqrt 3}{3} = \sqrt 3,\; $ so *yes, we can express/simplify* and the $3$'s "cancel out".

Comment: Hi, Amy. :-)...

Comment: Hello, dear friend! I've been watching for you!!

Comment: I am like a pounded steak Amy. Exhausted...

Comment: You deserve, then, to immerse yourself in a heavenly slumber!

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind words Amy. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You for sure wrote it incorrectly .See this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=d%2Fdx(sin3x%2Fsqrt%7B3%7D)

$$\dfrac1{\sqrt 3} \dfrac d{dx}(\sin3x)=\dfrac1{\sqrt 3}\times 3 \cos3x=\sqrt3 \cos3x$$

Comment: A hint for formatting: putting a backslash before functions like $\sin$ gets them in the usual font.